# Let's solve the [mystery]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I just noticed that we have a tag [mystery](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mystery). Its tag wiki excerpt rather unhelpfully says:

> a mystery is something that is difficult or impossible to understand or explain. Or a novel, play, or movie dealing with a puzzling crime, esp. a murder.

without giving any clue as to how the tag is meant to be used on this site. As for current usage, at the moment the tag appears on 20 story-ID questions and 10 others. Of those 10, some seem to have the tag just because the OP is asking about something they consider a mystery - [How do Horcruxes work?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/40118/31394), [Can someone explain the ending of "Enemy"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/123509/31394) - and some simply because they're about mystery stories, e.g. [Understanding the limericks in Asimov's mystery story, "Out of Sight"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/37760/31394) and [What's the sequence of events Milo discovers in "The Counterfifth Detective"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/15940/31394) The first of these usage types at least should be killed, otherwise [mystery](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mystery) could be used on nearly every question on the site; and the second is not usually how we use genre tags here.

**Should we keep this tag? If so, how should we be using it, and what should the tag wiki say?**

<sub>(Note that even getting rid of the tag entirely would require at most 10 manual edits, followed by a merge into [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification). Whatever we decide, it's not going to be a huge operation to "*make it so*".)</sub>

Comment: It doesn't seem particularly useful - Exterminate!

Comment: I don't think there are any experts on "mystery" specifically - either the genre or the tradecraft term; and can't really see anyone searching for mystery specific content. Have to agree with @Chenmunka

Comment: It's not even useful as a genre tag because the genre's not on topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from the voting on comments and the now-deleted answer here, people seem to be generally against the existence of the [mystery](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mystery) tag. I've gone ahead and burninated it.

As mentioned above, its use on *any question about something the OP considers a mystery* is completely awful: by that standard, the tag could be used on pretty much every question on the site. Its use on story-ID questions could arguably be OK - we use other genre tags that way all the time - but the fact that the tag has been used so inappropriately so much suggests that if we keep it around, it'll just continue being used inappropriately. So:

[image: BURNINATED!]